# Can we disable JSX self closing tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, tags, jsx

I received this error:

Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for

The input tag is not required to be closed. How can I avoid having to add a slash to my code?

I'm not here for JSX isn't HTML5, just want to know if its possible as some kind of config or something.

Comment: The syntax of JSX requires you to close all tags (either with a trailing `/`, or a separate `</tagnamehere>`). There's no config options to turn this off.

Comment: i guess you could pre-process with a regexp, but that's got a lot of drawbacks... self-closing tags were a mistake, and you won't see any new ones, ever.

Comment: JSX stands for *JavaScript Extension*. There are no modifiers to change core JS syntax, so there are no such modifiers for JSX.

Comment: @estus: clearly, the tag "literals" are not core JS, so they _could_ be interpreted however the runtime wants. i would guess the reason you can't is the same as why JSON requires quoted keys: it keeps the parser code a lot simpler.

Comment: @dandavis They are the extension over core JS and it's quite specific, https://facebook.github.io/jsx/ . Of course, self-closing tags are there to make parsing easier. But the reason why JSX syntax isn't configurable is because it's language syntax, not just random markup.

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure i get your point about "language syntax" vs "random markup". what language is JSX syntax? it throws a SyntaxError in JS, so clearly there's some interpretation being done by something, and i argue that that something can do something else if it were coded to do so. I understand the react marketing and that they want you to keep the superset-ed-ness in mind when coding, but it's more than possible to alter it to use, say parens instead of angle brackets, or to white-list self-closing tag names, if so desired.

Comment: how would we use the whitelist? @dandavis